# How to edit a file from the command line Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line, text-editor

How to open and edit the file in the command line? I tried to use the command `open`:

```
sudo open -e /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

but the file is `Locked` and I can not change anything.

[image]

I need to edit a lot of text and use `nano` or `vim` is not very convenient.

Comment: You may not like it, but `sudo vi` is probably the easiest way to do this.

Comment: I suspect this is because the permission elevation is for the `open` command not `TextEdit` itself. You should use a different editor that can have its binary run properly from the command line like [SublimeText](http://www.sublimetext.com/) (`sudo subl /path/to/file`) or [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) (`sudo mate /path/to/file`). Or just suck it up and use `vi` or `nano` :-)

Comment: how to save the edited file in terminal on mac

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suspect this is because the permission elevation is for the `open` command, not TextEdit itself.

You should use a different editor that can have its binary run properly from the command line like [SublimeText](http://www.sublimetext.com/) (`sudo subl /path/to/file`) or [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) (`sudo mate /path/to/file`). Or just suck it up and use `vi` or `nano` :-)

If you're going to be doing a lot of this type of thing TextEdit is probably the least desirable editor to use anyhow.

Answer (score 18):

```
sudo open -a TextEdit /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Comment: Right. I've just tried it on my machine. I meant that you want a way to open the file with different app from command line. You can use @Steven answer to make a copy, also you can click "Locked" in the title bar, uncheck locked checkbox and it will offer you to make a duplicate.

Comment: Works for simple files!

Comment: OS X Lion will prevent this working correctly. Even though you are running as a superuser

Comment: This command is not working for OS 12

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to edit those locked files is to make a copy of them, edit the copy, and then replace the file:

```
cp /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf ~/httpd-vhosts.conf
open ~/httpd-vhosts.conf

sudo mv /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf.bkup
sudo mv ~/httpd-vhosts.conf /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```